# Adobe InDesign Javascript Error! Error number: 55 Error String: Object does not support the property or method 'documentPreferences'

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign

I'm getting an error when I try to run the following code in InDesign.
I'm actually getting this code directly from an Adobe tutorial, not sure why they'd get their own code wrong. Any way you could help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

```
try{myFont = app.fonts.item("Arial");
   }
catch (myError){};
var myDocument = app.documents.item(0);

with(myDocument){

    var myPage = pages.item(0);
    var myBounds = myGetBounds(myPage,myDocument);

    with(myDocument.pages.item(0)){
        //Get a reference to the text frame.
        var myTextFrame = textFrames.item(0);
        //Change the size of the text frame.
        myTextFrame.geometricBounds = myBounds;
        var myParagraph = myTextFrame.paragraphs.item(0);
        myParagraph.appliedFont = myFont;
        myParagraph.justification = Justification.centerAlign;
        myParagraph.pointSize = 48;
    }

}
    //myGetBounds is a function that returns the bounds 
    //of the "live area" of a page.
function myGetBounds(myDocument, myPage){
    var myPageWidth = myDocument.documentPreferences.pageWidth;
    var myPageHeight = myDocument.documentPreferences.pageHeight;

    if(myPage.side == PageSideOptions.leftHand){
        var myX2 = myPage.marginPreferences.left;
        var myX1 = myPage.marginPreferences.right;
    }else{
        var myX1 = myPage.marginPreferences.left;
        var myX2 = myPage.marginPreferences.right;
    }
    var myY1 = myPage.marginPreferences.top;
    var myX2 = myPageWidth - myX2;
    var myY2 = myPageHeight - myPage.marginPreferences.bottom;
    return [myY1, myX1, myY2, myX2];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like in the `myGetBounds()` function you are passing the arguments in the wrong order.

In the function definition you can see that the document should be passed first and then the page second, but in the line starting with `var myBounds` you do it the other way around.

So the line should probably be:

```js
var myBounds = myGetBounds(myDocument, myPage);
```